# Quotient of Arguments to a Logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem I'm working on is:

*There are $p, q > 0$ satisfying $\log_9p=\log_{12}q=\log_{16}(p+q)$. Find $q/p$.*

---

I set all of the logarithms equal to a variable $t$, so I could say $$9^t=p,12^t=q,16^t=p+q$$
which implies $$9^t+12^t=16^t.$$

I also know that $$\frac{q}{p}=\frac{12^t}{9^t}=\left( \frac{4}{3} \right) ^t$$
$$\frac{p+q}{q}=\frac{16^t}{12^t}=\left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^t$$
and therefore
$$\frac{q}{p} = \frac{p+q}{q}.$$

I haven't gotten any farther than this, so does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $9\cdot 16=144=12^2$. Thus $q^2=p(p+q)$. Rewrite as
$$q^2-pq-p^2=0.$$
Divide through by $p^2$. We get
$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^2-\frac{q}{p}-1=0.$$
Solve this quadratic equation for $\dfrac{q}{p}$, using the Quadratic Formula.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\dfrac{p+q}{q} = \dfrac{p}{q} + 1 = \dfrac{1}{q/p} + 1$. Substituting $x = \dfrac{q}{p}$ into your equation, you thus get
$$x = \dfrac{1}{x} + 1$$
and multiplying through by $x$ gives you $x^2=1+x$. This is a quadratic equation, which you can solve for $x$ (which is equal to $\frac{q}{p}$).

Keep in mind that it is specified that $p,q > 0$.